# Storing an object column value based on it's children values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Location` that `has_many` child attributes called `MapClassifiers`.  For example:

**Location**
id: 1
name: "Vasona Park"

**Map Classifier**
name: "city"
value: "Los Gatos"
location_id: 1

**Map Classifier**
name: "county"
value: "Santa Clara"
location_id: 1

**Map Classifier**
name: "near_water"
value: true
location_id: 1

The data models are set up like this so users can create an unlimited number of custom `Map Classifiers` for locations.

In this example, is there a way to automatically generate a column value in the `Location` object based on the `MapClassifier` values?  For example:

**Location**
id: 1
name: "Vasona Park"
map_classifier_information: {:city => "Los Gatos", :county => "Santa Clara", :near_water => true}

Ideally this map_classifier_information column would update any time a new `MapClassifier` is added to a `Location`.

Comment: you can create a callback on after create for the map classifier to update the column on location

Comment: @xploshioOn perfect, thank you